# Python - Making a "character" jump to another object's x, y ordinates while facing the 'go to' objects front

Tags: python, game-engine

I know little of code so this is a bit difficult to me.

This is just the set up for a 'player' to grab a crate and pull it back and forth.
I have 4 empty triggers set up so the crate can be grab from each of the 4 sides

However I want the 'player' to copy the x, y position and direction of the trigger that the player initiates the grab.

*Basically, I want the player's movement to be locked into a specific position as it moves the crate around."

Here's what I current have written

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

own = cont.owner



scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

trigger1 = scene.objects["trigger1"]

player = scene.objects["player"]



q = cont.sensors["Keyboard"]



if q.positive:

player.worldPosition = trigger1.worldPosition
```

I just don't know how to separate "worldPosition" into x, y, z

Comment: trigger1.worldPosition.x trigger1.worldPosition.y trigger1.worldPosition.z

Comment: That worked but I still need a 'worldRotation' command

Comment: [worldOrientation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=world%20orientation#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldOrientation)